# Hide/show state of div react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

suppose i have a div element

```
<div
     style={{
                borderTopLeftRadius: "10px",
                borderTopRightRadius: "10px",
                background: "#edf2f8",
                border: "1px solid #edf2f8",
                borderBottom: "0px",
                width:"300px",
                marginLeft:"20px",
                backgroundPosition: "center",
                
              }}

  >
    hello world
 </div>
```

I want to use the onclick function to hide/show state of the div . For example when a user clicks in the div I hide it .. How can I achieve that in react ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store a display value in component state and toggle it via the `onClick` handler. Conditionally render the entire div.

Example:

```
function App() {
  const [display, setDisplay] = React.useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {display && (
        <div
          onClick={() => setDisplay(false)}
          style={{
            borderTopLeftRadius: "10px",
            borderTopRightRadius: "10px",
            background: "#edf2f8",
            border: "1px solid #edf2f8",
            borderBottom: "0px",
            width: "300px",
            marginLeft: "20px",
            backgroundPosition: "center"
          }}
        >
          hello world
        </div>
      )}
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setDisplay(true)}>
        Reply
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit hide-show-state-of-div-react]

Comment: this works but now when i try to display the div again it doesn't return until i refresh the page

Comment: @kaay Hard to say without seeing what the code you are using is actually doing. Can you add an update to your question?

Comment: <div
              style={{
                borderTopLeftRadius: "10px",
                borderTopRightRadius: "10px",
                background: "#edf2f8",
                border: "1px solid #edf2f8",
                borderBottom: "0px",
                width: "300px",
                marginLeft: "20px",
                backgroundPosition: "center",
                display: display ? "initial" : "none",
              }}
              onClick={() => setDisplay((display) => !display)}
            >
              {props.replyMessage.content}
            </div>

Comment: @kaay Ah, I see, yeah... if you hide the div it isn't clickable to toggle the state and make visible again. What is the use case here? Do you need to hide the div?

Comment: okay .. am building a chat application. I'm trying to implement the concept of replying to a specific message in a chat. so a user does press the reply button to reply to a message but I want to give him the option of canceling/closing the reply message div in case he changes his mind... the above code I what I was using to capture the message you are replying ( minus variables am using ). so I want to use the concept of display none to hide the reply in case the user chooses to cancel which you have helped me with. but now when I try to press the reply button again the message isn't displayed

Comment: @kaay Ok, it sounds more like you want this "show/hide" state to live in the parent component rendering the "replay message UI" where it's passed a callback to set the state in the parent to hide itself. I'm assuming the "reply button" is what is used to toggle it "visible". Does this make sense?

Comment: yes i do you think i can acheive that

Comment: @kaay Sure, this would be trivial. Can you update your question to be more representative of your *actual* use case for us? This is so we can write a more accurate answer.

Comment: @kaay I have updated my answer, please take a look when you can.